# Angular tranform multiple AngularFireDatabase.object calls into an Iterable Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I have a list of keys I retrieved from my google cloud realtime database using `AngularFireDatabase.list()` function and I want to run a query on each of the keys to get information associated with them. I have been doing this using `AngularFireDatabase.object('path/${key}')` in a forEach loop. How can merge all of those seperate queries into an iterable observable like of type `Observable<Array<any>>` so I can use the `async` pipe in my html template?

Example of what I have so far:

```
this.db.getEditors().snapshotChanges().subscribe(userRoles => {
  this.activeEditors = Observable.from(userRoles.map(x => x.key)).flatMap(x => this.db.afDb.object(`/users/${x}`)
    .valueChanges()).filter(x => x !== null).map(x => [{key : x.value}]);
});
```

Where `this.activeEditors` is of type `Observable<Array<any>>`

HTML:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let editor of activeEditors | async">
    <ion-title>{{editor.displayName}}</ion-title>
    <ion-label>{{editor.email}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

The problem im running into in this code is the final `.map()` call just returns an array of the last object. How would I be able to get all the values into the `this.activeEditors` variable, instead of just the last item?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.activeEditors = this.db.getEditors().snapshotChanges().switchMap(editors =>
  Observable.combineLatest(editors.map { editor =>
    this.db.afDb.object(`/users/${editor.key}`)
      .valueChanges()
      .map(...)
  })
).filter(...);
```

Use a `switchMap` on the `snapshotChanges()`, then `combineLatest` a mapping of further fetches. `filter` from there.